# How do I get individual number of characters, digits from a string?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

How would i get the individual number of digits, characters and non-alpha numeric characters from a string?

For example, the string "abc99@" would have (3 letters, 2 digits and 1 non alpha numeric character).

At the moment i have the following code but it gets the total characters where as i want individual. How would i do this.

```
read input
echo ${#input}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need additional tools:

```
letters="${input//[^a-zA-Z]}"; echo "${letters}: ${#letters}"
digits="${input//[^0-9]}"; echo "${digits}: ${#digits}"
other="${input//[0-9a-zA-Z]}"; echo "${other}: ${#other}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `grep -o` and `wc -l`:

```
s="abc99."

# number of digits
grep -o '[0-9]' <<< "$s" | wc -l
2

# number of alphabets
grep -o '[a-zA-Z]' <<< "$s" | wc -l
3

# number of non-alphanumerics
grep -o '[^0-9a-zA-Z]' <<< "$s" | wc -l
1
```

Comment: `<<<` is here string format to pass value of variable to `grep` command.